# Google Earth Engine - Map.addLayer

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a possibility to do "Map.addLayer" so the image is not already displayed in the output but can be loaded in via check mark in the layer dropdown?

(I would like to do the reverse of the default "Map.addLayer"..... visual go through multiple images, by default, all with Map.addLayer are displayed and I wondered if there is a better way, then manually disable each Layer in the Output by clicking away the check mark).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation

> **Map.addLayer(eeObject, *visParams, name, shown, opacity)***
>
> Adds a given EE object to the map as a layer.
>
> Returns the new map layer.
>
> Arguments:
>
> **eeObject (Collection|Feature|Image|MapId):** The object to
>   add to the map.
>
> **visParams
>   (FeatureVisualizationParameters|ImageVisualizationParameters,
>   optional):** The visualization parameters. For Images and
>   ImageCollection, see ee.data.getMapId for valid parameters. For
>   Features and FeatureCollections, the only supported key is "color", as
>   a CSS 3.0 color string or a hex string in "RRGGBB" format.
>
> **name (String, optional):** The name of the layer. Defaults to "Layer N".
>
> **shown (Boolean, optional):** A flag indicating whether the layer should
>   be on by default.
>
> **opacity (Number, optional):** The layer's opacity represented as a
>   number between 0 and 1. Defaults to 1.
>
> **Returns: ui.Map.Layer**

I think what you want is done by parameter **shown**. Set it to *false* and the image will be added to the `Map` but not displayed

Comment: Thank You for your help, that's exactly what I was looking for :)